# Centered or not?

Tags: bathroom

Should I center these tiles and end up with a 4.5” cut tile under the vanity and along the right wall, or should I work off the vanity and have a 9” cut tile line again the right wall? The tiles are 15 x 30”. The bathroom is 40 sqft.[image]

Comment: I think for most having them centred is recommended.  It usually makes the room look even.  You can try laying them out both ways(uncut) and see.

Comment: Avoiding really small cuts (perhaps < 2") to avoid certain types of problems is important in terms of functionality (ease of installation, durability). Beyond that, this is as subjective as "what shade of off-white paint should I use".

Comment: I put large tiles in 2  bathrooms . Tile guy said lay them on 45 degree diagonal, looks fine .  Later, I put 18" tiles on a portico; 45 degrees looks good. Also not a bad cutting job because the cut pieces each fit somewhere. I used wet saw with diamond blade.

Comment: A professional would either lay them diagonally or center them and/or make a feature of the border.

Comment: It's not like it's gonna take fewer tiles (unless you break some); you might as well go with the most pleasing "centered" method.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

How about option 3?

Work off the wall and have the 9" cut 'under' the vanity.  (I'm not saying it's best, but another option).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I've found that the tiles are centered with equal cuts on both sides. The other common option is to work from the wall toward the vanity and cut those tiles. Then it looks like the room was completely tiles and the vanity added later.